# php sort array and rank specific field

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ranking

I am trying to output a ranking by lowest number first for a particular field (`OurPrice`) based on numeric values.

`var_dump` Result

```
$myarray = array_filter($rankresult);
natsort($myarray); 

array(6) { 
    ["Comp7"]=> string(3) "189" 
    ["OurPrice"]=> string(3) "189" 
    ["Comp9"]=> string(6) "198.99" 
    ["Comp6"]=> string(3) "208" 
    ["Comp3"]=> string(6) "226.97" 
    ["Comp4"]=> string(3) "274" 
}
```

You will notice that there are 6 total in the count and two of which are the same number, therefore it would equal the same rank (ie. Comp7 and OurPrice are both ranked 1 of 6).

Desired Output:

**Our Price Rank = 1 of 6**

Comment: I don't know where to go from here.  Isn't there a way to grab the Rank order of "OurPrice"?

Comment: @ToddN: How should be the output, just **Our Price Rank = 1 of 6** ?

Comment: Yes so basically I would be using `echo "Our Price Rank" . $rank . " of " . $count";`  Something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this code

```
 $newarray = (array_unique(array_values($myarray)));
 $rank = array_search($myarray['OurPrice'],$newarray)+1;
 $count = count($myarray));
 echo "Our Price Rank" . $rank . " of " . $count"
```

Comment: Similarly to my answer, I like this approach given my initial data in the question.  The main point being array_search as mentioned by Jonathans post to.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already sorted the values (which it appears you have), you could simply tell them the index at which the "OurProduct" key exists.

```
$keys = array_keys( $array );
$rank = array_search( "OurPrice", $keys );

printf( "We rank %d of %d", ++$rank, count($keys) );
```

Try it online: http://codepad.org/qIwTGBzG